# Using multiple backreference in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, backreference

I am trying to use multiple backreference in Perl, to match 5 different patterns, but I am getting no match except for the first one.

I tried the following:

```
my $string = ">abc|XYUXYU|KIOKEIK_7XNCU Happy, not-happy apple banana X ORIG=Came from trees NBMR 12345 OZ=1213379 NG=popZ AZ=2 BU=1";
$string =~ m/>(abc)|(.*)|.*ORIG=(.*)[A-Z].*NG=(.*)\s(.*)\s/;

print "First match should be 'abc'. We got: $1\n";
print "Second match should be 'XYUXYU'. We got: $2\n";
print "Third match should be 'Came from trees'. We got: $3\n";
print "Fourth match should be 'popZ'. We got: $4\n";
print "Fifth match should be 'AZ=2'. We got: $5\n";
```

I wanted as output:

```
First match should be 'abc'. We got: abc
Second match should be 'XYUXYU'. We got: XYUXYU
Third match should be 'Came from trees'. We got: Came from trees
Fourth match should be 'popZ'. We got: popZ
Fifth match should be 'AZ=2'. We got: AZ=2
```

Any clue how to solve this in the correct way on Perl?

Comment: The name of the language is Perl, not PERL. It's not an acronym

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `|` by prepending `\` as they otherwise mean an alternation (`a|b` matches `a` or `b`). And for your third match you have to make the quantifier `*` non greedy by appending `?`. And you need to tweak the pattern following the third capture group a little to match a space an at least one upper character (It's not entirely clear here what the overall possibilities are as you just gave an expample without further details. It might need further adaption.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = ">abc|XYUXYU|KIOKEIK_7XNCU Happy, not-happy apple banana X ORIG=Came from trees NBMR 12345 OZ=1213379 NG=popZ AZ=2 BU=1";
$string =~ m/>(abc)\|(.*)\|.*ORIG=(.*?)\s[A-Z]+.*NG=(.*)\s(.*)\s/;

print "First match should be 'abc'. We got: $1\n";
print "Second match should be 'XYUXYU'. We got: $2\n";
print "Third match should be 'Came from trees'. We got: $3\n";
print "Fourth match should be 'popZ'. We got: $4\n";
print "Fifth match should be 'AZ=2'. We got: $5\n";
```

Output:

```
First match should be 'abc'. We got: abc
Second match should be 'XYUXYU'. We got: XYUXYU
Third match should be 'Came from trees'. We got: Came from trees
Fourth match should be 'popZ'. We got: popZ
Fifth match should be 'AZ=2'. We got: AZ=2
```

Comment: I gave this case modified from similar patterns in multiple text files. It works fine with your answer. Thanks :)